# JQ delete property based other property value

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to write a JQ filter allowing me to selectively filter object properties based on other of it's values.

For example, given following input

```
{
"object1": {
"Type": "Type1",
"Properties": {
  "Property1": "blablabla",
  "Property2": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Surname",
      "Value": "yyy"
    }
  ],
  "Property3": "xxx"
 }
},
"object2": {
"Type": "Type2",
"Properties": {
  "Property1": "blablabla",
  "Property2": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Surname",
      "Value": "yyy"
    }
  ],
  "Property3": "xxx"
  }
 }
}
```

I would like to construct a filter, that based upon the object type, say "Type2", deletes or clears a property of that object, say Property2.
The resulting output would then be:

```
{
"object1": {
"Type": "Type1",
"Properties": {
  "Property1": "blablabla",
  "Property2": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Surname",
      "Value": "yyy"
    }
  ],
  "Property3": "xxx"
 }
},
"object2": {
"Type": "Type2",
"Properties": {
  "Property1": "blablabla",
  "Property3": "xxx"
  }
 }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple.  Find the objects that you want to update, then update them.

Look through the values of your root object, filtering them based on your condition, the update the `Properties` property deleting the property you want.

```
(.[] | select(.Type == "Type2")).Properties |= del(.Property2)
```

Using `.[]` on an object yields all property values of an object.  Also worth mentioning, when you update a value using assignments, the result of the expression just returns the input (in other words, it doesn't change the context).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work ok for exact matches. 
Would this be possible for regex-matches as well ?

I'm trying: 

`.["Resources"]|(.[] | select(.Type | match("type2";"i")?)).Properties  |= del(.Property2)`

This does not seem to work however.

Comment: In that case, you would want to use `test`, but it looks like there's a precedence issue when using the regular expression filters here. `Invalid path expression near attempt to access element "Properties"...`  It seems to only do that when trying to do the update/reassignment. Seems to be a bug in the parser to me.

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach:

```
.[] |= (if .Type == "Type2" then delpaths([["Properties", "Property2"]]) else . end)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how it would resolve issue ?